# Getting ready to write my first C program, getting Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT

Tags: node.js, c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get to the point that my "Hello World" will work, but am running into this error.

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "$C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding/Hello World.c"
Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

I've set up my launch.json, and c_cpp_properties, but am not entirely sure I set them up correctly, as I am doing self-taught, and am having trouble finding useful examples online.

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [   
            {
                "type": "node",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Program",
                "program": "$C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding/Hello World.c"
                ,"cwd": "$C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding"
            }
          ,{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "$C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding/Hello World.c"
          }
        ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: If your Windows system can't find c:\WINDOWS\Ststem32\cmd.exe, it is broken in ways that have nothing to do with your programming environment.

Comment: most of the time people compile a c program first and do not use node.exe

Comment: (replying to Lee Daniel Crocker) I'm able to find it perfectly fine on my own, so I'm wondering if I need to change a setting somewhere or add in some bit of code on one of the aforementioned files to direct it to the correct location? I don't know what I would do for that though.

Comment: rioV8, I'm not sure what node.exe is, I assume you mean ```"type": "node",```, but I don't know what other "types" there are to use, as it was the default option when adding a configuration following parts of the VSCode user guide.

Comment: Forgive me, but what are you dong calling `node.exe` with `Hello_World.c` as an argument? Forget fighting with the VS project setup. Open the *VS Developers Command Prompt*, and `cd C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Coding/` and then type `cl /w3 /Ox /FeHello_World /Tc Hello_World.c` and then type `Hello_World` -- done. `cl.exe` is the compiler used by VS, and you can use it from the command-line to build any C file you like (or multiple C files) without having to fight the json in VS to do it. Type `cl /?` to see all options.

Comment: David C. Rankin, I ended up finding myself at "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations" gif, and followed the "add a new configuration", but I don't know how/why node.exe is assigned, or where I can change that, but now I see why you are asking that.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe it'd be better for me to start over overall. I don't have a VS Developers Command Prompt, not sure why, but that prevents me from taking further action with David's instrcution.

Comment: Oh, I feel like a moron, "node" was an example, but not really pertaining to what I needed. Back to nearly square one!

Answer (score 0):

Before anything: Do you have a C compiler in your machine? Or even Visual Studio? In order to compile C code using VS Code in Windows you need to have a compiler installed. VS Code does not have one built in. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)

If you do not have Visual Studio installed you need at least Microsoft C++ Build Tools or another windows C/C++ compiler, like gcc or CLang installed. Or all of them.

Then you configure VS Code to use then, editing the .json files and configuring the so called "build tasks'